# Why this WHERE condition that have to select records in a specified timeframe is not working as expected?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem working on this **MySql** query:

```
SELECT
    CCMD.id                                                                 AS crop_calendar_message_details_id,
    CCMD.broadcasting_start_date                                            AS broadcasting_start_date,
    CCMD.broadcasting_end_date                                              AS broadcasting_end_date,
    CCMD.creation_date                                                      AS creation_date,
    CCM.id                                                                  AS message_id,
    CCM.content_en                                                          AS content_en,
    IFNULL(CCMN.content, CCM.content_en)                                    AS content,
    CCMN.audio_link                                                         AS audio_link,
    CCMD.crop_action_details_id                                             AS crop_action_details_id

FROM CropCalendarMessageDetails                                                                             AS CCMD

INNER JOIN CropCalendarMessage                                                                              AS CCM
      ON CCMD.crop_calendar_message_id = CCM.id
LEFT JOIN CropCalendarMessageName                                                                           AS CCMN
     ON CCMN.crop_calendar_message_id = CCM.id AND CCMN.language_id = :language_id 

INNER JOIN CropActionDetails                                                                                AS CAD
      ON CCMD.crop_action_details_id = CAD.id  

WHERE 
    CCMD.commodity_id = 10
AND
    CCMD.country_id = 2
AND
    CAD.id = :cad_id 
AND 
    CCMD.broadcasting_start_date >= CURDATE() 
AND 
    CURDATE() <= CCMD.broadcasting_end_date 
ORDER BY CCMD.broadcasting_start_date
```

I have some records that have the following fixed values for thes date fields:

```
CCMD.broadcasting_start_date = 22/12/2018 23:59:00

CCMD.broadcasting_end_date = 30/05/2018
```

So in theory my query should skip these values because I have set this section on my **WHERE** clause:

```
AND 
    CCMD.broadcasting_start_date >= CURDATE() 
AND 
    CURDATE() <= CCMD.broadcasting_end_date
```

The problem is that these records are returned by my query so this dates filter condition is not working.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: Which is your CURDATE() value?? It seems that you should use AND 
    CCMD.broadcasting_start_date< CURDATE() 
AND 
    CURDATE() > CCMD.broadcasting_end_date

Comment: BTW, you dont have your respective "aliases"  (CCMD, CCM and CAD) to the tables included above.  This would crash outright without them.

Comment: @nacho my CURDATE value is "28/06/2018"

Comment: *The problem is that these records are returned by my query* ... how is this a problem? What actually is returned? Nothing?

Comment: Try to use date so you avoid the time problems AND 
    date(CCMD.broadcasting_start_date) >= date(CURDATE())
AND 
    date(CURDATE()) <= date(CCMD.broadcasting_end_date )

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with date/time values and querying, I personally have always tried to apply >= and < the boundaries.  For example, if you wanted something for All activity within March, 2018, I would do

```
where '2018-03-01' <= DateTimeField 
  AND DateTimeField < '2018-04-01'
```

By doing greater or equal to the start of just a date, you get from midnight all the way through the date period.  As for the ending date, I always go LESS than the following day (hence April 1st).  So I get everything up to Mar 31 at 11:59:59pm.

This way you also dont need to mess with date conversion functions just to ensure something is on the same day or time-portions thereof.

Might this help in resolving the date/time considerations of your query.